# converting javascript array into html table in new window on click

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating data visualizations, and I have a button that will execute a JavaScript function and extract the first five rows from specified columns of data based on the user's selection:

```
getselection.onclick = function()
{
visual.Document.selection.getselection(
"City",                        \\identifies the selection
"Users",                       \\identifies the table
["Name", "Phone", "Zipcode"],  \\identifies the columns
5,
function(args)
        {
            log(dump(args, "visual.Document.selection.getselection", 2));
        });
};
```

The resulting output looks like this:

```
[Name]
0:  xxxxx
1:  xxxxx
2:  xxxxx

[Phone]
0:  xxxxx
1:  xxxxx
```

What I would like to do is to display the results of the users selection in an HTML table in a new window that opens upon click. I have seen a suggestions for doing something similar to this, but for some reason I can't seem to get them to work. Here is what I have so far:

```
function getSelMarking() {
visual.Document.selection.getMarking(
    "city",
    "Users",
    ["Name", "phone", "Zipcode"],
    5,
    function(args) {
        var UserIDs=dump(args);



        HTMLstring='<HTML>\n';
        HTMLstring+='<HEAD>\n';
        HTMLstring+='<TITLE>New Document</TITLE>\n';
        HTMLstring+='</HEAD>\n';
        HTMLstring+='<BODY>\n';
        HTMLstring+='<P>Hello World</P>\n';
        HTMLstring+='<table>\n';
        HTMLstring+='<tr>\n';
        HTMLstring+='<td>'+UserIDs+'</td>\n';
        HTMLstring+='<td>'+UserIDs+'</td>\n';
        HTMLstring+='<td>'+UserIDs+'</td>\n';
        HTMLstring+='</tr>\n';
        HTMLstring+='</table>\n';
        HTMLstring+='</BODY>\n';
        HTMLstring+='</HTML>';
        newwindow=window.open();
        newdocument=newwindow.document;
        newdocument.write(HTMLstring);
        newdocument.close();
        }
    );
}
```

Thats as far as I've gotten.  I am completely stuck on this - maybe I just don't have a good understanding of how the functions work? Regardless, thank you to anyone who can lend any type of assistance here.

i forgot to include the breakdown of the dump() function:

```
var dump = function(obj, name, indent, depth) {
if (depth > MAX_DUMP_DEPTH) {
    return indent + name + ": <Maximum Depth Reached>\n";
}

if (typeof(obj) == "object") {
    var child = null;
    var output = name + "\n";
    indent += "\t";
    for (var item in obj) {
         try {
            if (item.charAt(0) == '_')  {
                continue;
            }
            child = obj[item];
        } catch (e) {
            child = "<Unable to Evaluate>";
        }

        if (typeof child == "object") {
            output += dump(child, item, indent, depth + 1);
        } else if (typeof(child) == "function") {
            var functionName = String(child);
            functionName = functionName.substring(0, functionName.indexOf("{", 0) -     
10}
            output += "\t" + item + ": " + functionName + "\n";
        } else {
            var value = "";
            if (child == null) {
                value = "[null]";
            } else {
                value = child;
            }
            output += "\t" + item + ": " + value + "\n";
        }
    }
    return output + "\n";
} else {
    return obj;
}
};
```

Comment: are you using some library that you havent tagged? what is `visual` object? And are you getting any errors in your javascript console (hit F12 to get to the developers tools if you dont know what this is)

Comment: sorry, i should have included that script for the dump function, that is my mistake.  i believe that is the only thing i left out - the `visual` object refers to the data visualization.  i checked the console and there weren't any errors.  it seems to me at least like this is something i just dont know how to do, not so much a technical error.please let me know if you think there is something else i should be looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question.  the difficulty here was caused my lack of understanding as to how javascript handled arrays.  sorry everyone.